# Find all the object ids and convert to an array in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, primary-key, objectid

I want to use the output of find query in another find query where object ids are in string format. To achieve the same, I need to get an array of all object ids as an "array of strings" from a find query. Below is what I have tried:

```
courseList ={ 
        $or: [
            { createdBy: {$eq: ObjectId("60f6ae1733257a3bcfe581e7")} },
            { _shareWithUsers: ObjectId("60f6ae1733257a3bcfe581e7") }
        ]};
// get all the course ids   
db.courses.find(courseList, {_id: 1});
```

###### returns data in format like below:

```
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "60f6b1976f5afd4174faf6a3"
    }
  }
...
]
```

###### Experimented with map function but couldn't get the id array.

```
var courseIds = db.courses.find(courseList, {_id: 1}).map(v => v._id);
courseIds;

courseOIDStrings = courseIds.map(function (oid) {
    console.log(Object.keys(oid));
    return oid._id;
});
```

Query where the result need to be used:

```
db.courseassets.find({ 
    { _courseId: {$in: db.courses.find(courseList)} },
    {_id: 1, createdBy: 1, _assetId: 1 }
)
```

Note: I am trying these in MongoDB playground in VSCode.

Comment: can you share a sample of input and expected output? also check [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/)

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

```
db.courses.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      $or: [
        {
          createdBy: {
            $eq: ObjectId("60f6ae1733257a3bcfe581e7")
          }
        },
        {
          _shareWithUsers: ObjectId("60f6ae1733257a3bcfe581e7")
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "courseassets",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "_courseId",
      "as": "docs"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$docs"
  },
  {
    "$replaceWith": "$docs"
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l0_FUxvrQXE)

---

**Method 2**

```
db.courseassets.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "courses",
      "localField": "_courseId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "docs",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$match": {
            $or: [
              {
                createdBy: { $eq: ObjectId("60f6ae1733257a3bcfe581e7") }
              },
              {
                _shareWithUsers: ObjectId("60f6ae1733257a3bcfe581e7")
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      docs: { "$ne": [] }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unset": "docs"
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_NM_q_yDsbE)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the data from mongodb and then use map function to get arrays of ids

```
const data = await this.model.find({})
IdsArray = data.map((element: any) => {
  return element?._id
})
```